# Bootstrap only partially functional in rails -- glyphicons not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, glyphicons

I can't get my glyphicons to work in my Rails asset pipeline.

In `stylesheets/application.sass`, I have...

```
@import "bootstrap-sprockets"
@import "bootstrap"
@import "glyphicons"
```

I am using the `bootstrap-sass` and `sass-rails` gems

In `stylesheets/glyphicons.css`, I have...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'));
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) format('woff'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')) format('truetype'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')) format('svg');
}
```

It's weird, because this (below) works fine, giving me the red danger button...

```
<a class="detete btn btn-danger" href="#">x</a>
```

...while this one (below) does not work, not giving me either the grey default button or the star icon...

```
<a class="btn" href="#"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i></a>
```

That's why I say Bootstrap is only working "partially" for me.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Have you added the following line to your application.js. you have not mentioned anything about your application.js here. I hope this will help you

```
//= require jquery
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
```

you can check the following link
https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass

Comment: I've actually go those. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

By default Glyphicons font directory set to fonts folder. Instead you should define it with `asset_path` . So try add below code in `app/assets/stylesheets/application.css.scs`.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot'));
  src: url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot?#iefix')) format('embedded-opentype'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff')) format('woff'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf')) format('truetype'), url(asset_path('glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg#glyphicons_halflingsregular')) format('svg');
}`
```

You might also need to make change in `config/application.rb`   file.

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
```

Comment: I made these changes and additions you recommend, but it still does not work.  Also, I can't figure out why the grey `btn` won't come up either, while the red `btn btn-danger` does come up.  It seems so strange.  It makes me think that I don't have the complete bootstrap package, but I should if I'm using the `bootstrap-sass` gem. Very strange.  Thanks.